# Moving physical SVN server to virtual server

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I have a physical SVN server, where VisualSVN Server is installed.
Repositories are located a network storage.

Now, I would like to install a new SVN server on a Virtual Machine, but I would like to link that new VisualSVN Server installation to current repositories location.

- Is it possible, or I need to make a dump?
- If it is possible? What steps should I follow?

Comment: This question should be asked at ServerFault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You do not need to dump-load your existing repositories in this case. Just install VisualSVN Server and point it to the repositories root location. You may need to adjust security permissions to the share BTW.
- 1. Install VisualSVN Server on a VM,
  2. Copy `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\certs` folder (it's where VisualSVN Server stores certificates).
  3. Copy `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\http-custom.conf` (if you modified the conf file on your current server and want to use it on new server).

There are two ways to migrate VisualSVN Server settings:

1. You may set everything manually when you setup VisualSVN Server and then through VisualSVN Server Manager,
2. Since server settings are stored in Windows Registry you may import them and then export to new machine. Settings are stored in the following registry branches:

   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VisualSVN\VisualSVN Server
     (for 64 bit OS)
   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VisualSVN\VisualSVN Server (for 32 bit OS)

You have to run `svn switch --relocate` to switch working copies to a new
URL (if URL to new server's URL changes). Check the command-line reference: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/switch/.